# ConversationCallback.onConversation() is late to be called

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When failing in OUTGOING INVITE (due to TwilioConversationsClient.CONVERSATION_PARTICIPANT_NOT_AVAILABLE),
it's rarely too late that ConversationCallback.onConversation() is called.
Normally it's called in 1-2sec, but in the case it takes more than 10sec.

I cannot have the steps to reproduce.
Please help me.

Details:

- SDK0.12.2 (July 6, 2016), Conversations Library 0.12.2, Twilio Common 0.6.1
- ASUS ZenPad 8.0 (Z380KL), Android 5.0.2

Comment: It would be best to send this information to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and ask for it to be passed on to the Video team to review the issue. If you can provide your code and the exact steps that cause this, that would be really useful. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I will.